# Add column if value is in another column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, isin

One of my dataframe is:

```
     name    value
0    Harry     a
1    Kenny     b
2    Zoey      h
```

another is:

```
     list                    topic
0    Jame, Harry, Noah      topic1
1    lee, zee               topic2
```

I want if any of the names of dataframe1 is in list of dataframe2 it should add a name column 'present' in dataframe1 with the values as of the respective topic.

```
     name    value   present
0    Harry     a      topic1
1    Kenny     b       none
2    Zoey      h       none
```

***UPDATED QUERY***

df1

```
     name        value
0    Harry Lee     a
1    Kenny         b
2    Zoey          h
```

df2 is same and desired result is

```
     name    value   present
0 Harry Lee    a      topic1 topic2
1    Kenny     b       none
2    Zoey      h       none
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to trim the df1 with `explode` then we can do `map`

```
df1['list'] = df1['list'].str.split(',')
s = df1.explode('list')
df['present'] = df.name.map(dict(zip(s['list'],s['topic'])))
df
Out[550]: 
    name value present
0  Harry     a  topic1
1  Kenny     b     NaN
2   Zoey     h     NaN
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode', this is the error I am facing

Comment: @TanishkaBansal update your panda will help

Comment: Also, what if df1 has one of its value as Harry Lee  and the desired result in present should be topic1 topic2 , how to do this one?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"name":['Harry', 'Kenny', 'Zoey'], "value":["a", "b", "h"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"list": ["Jame, Harry, Noah", "lee, zee"], "topic": ["topic1", "topic2"]})

def add_column(x):
    try:
        present = df2[df2['list'].str.contains(x)].iloc[0,1]
    except IndexError:
        present = np.NAN
    return present
df1['present'] = df1['name'].apply(add_column)
```

Comment: Also, what if df1 has one of its value as Harry Lee  and the desired result in present should be topic1 topic2 , how to do this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the `list` column of the second dataframe, then merge it back with the first dataframe on `name` and `list` columns doing the `left` join, then drop the `list` column and `fillna` with `None`:

```py
df1.merge(df2.explode('list'), left_on='name', right_on='list', how='left').drop(columns='list').fillna('None')

    name value   topic
0  Harry     a  topic1
1  Kenny     b    None
2   Zoey     h    None
```

Comment: This answer in in the "low quality answers queue".